# no matching function to call to

Tags: c++, qt

I'm calling this from my designing class and adding them later to the layout but I always get error messages with the function `ladeBild(QLabel l, QString s)`

```
    void Levels::erzeugen(Levels *)
{
....

    ladeBild(l01,"l01.png");
    ladeBild(l02,"l02.png");
    ladeBild(l03,"l03.png");
    ladeBild(l04,"l04.png");
    ladeBild(l05,"l05.png");
    ladeBild(l06,"l06.png");
    ladeBild(l07,"l07.png");
    ladeBild(l08,"l08.png");
    ladeBild(l09,"l09.png");
    ladeBild(l10,"l10.png");
    ladeBild(l11,"l11.png");
    ladeBild(l12,"l12.png");
...
}

    void Levels::ladeBild(QLabel l,QString s)
{

    l = new QLabel();
    l.setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    l.setAutoFillBackground(true);
    image = new QImage(s);//Muss im debug-Ordner sein!!!
    l.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
    l.setMaximumHeight(image->height());
    l.setMaximumWidth(image->width());

}
```

And I get the following error message (for each call to `ladeBild`)

> ```
> In member function 'void Levels::erzeugen(Levels*)': Fehler:no
> matching function for call to 'Levels::ladeBild(QLabel*&, const char
> [8])' candidates are: void Levels::ladeBild(QLabel, QString) Fehler:no
> match for 'operator=' in 'l = (QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(0u), (operator
> new(20u), (<statement>, ((QLabel*)<anonymous>))))' candidates are:
> QLabel& QLabel::operator=(const QLabel&)`
> ```

Can't fix this problem ...

Comment: `l = new QLabel();` - You're trying to assign a `QLabel*` to a `QLabel` here.

Comment: Please copy/paste code into your question to the extent possible - for what you posted you should also get an error on the line that chris commented on.

Answer (score 2):

`Levels::ladeBild` expects a `QLabel`, but it should be `QLabel*`.

Comment: `QLabel` like all `QObject` derived instances should be created on the heap, so the method signature should be made to accept a pointer, especially considering you declare a `QLabel` on heap and try to assign it - my answer _is correct_.  However, if you are seeing more errors it is because the compiler is getting further into your code and revealing more problems.